# Time in a perfect vacuum?

Tags: speed-of-light, time, vacuum

If we were able to make a perfect vacuum with no forms of energy in, including all forms of light would time still go on in that vacuum and if it doesn't how would we tell that it doesn't?
Then if we could see that there is no time flowing does that mean that the energy flowing at the speed of light creates the flow of time?

Comment: Why do you suspect that removing energy would remove time?

Comment: I think this questiobn asks whether vacuum states are time-dependent.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98917/2451

Comment: ooh sorry it is a duplicate i didn't see that one also i suspect that removing energy because time is a concept that we can observer by things changing and that relies on energy being transferred so i thought that no energy in the vacuum would mean no time in that vacuum

Comment: If we made this situation, there would be no way to know that this pocket of space actually exists because any observation of its existence could only be done by introducing some form of energy that would violate its energy-free state. We could hypothesize about its existence, but that leads us nowhere. There is no such thing as a truly passive measurement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to distinguish between spacetime and proper time:

The vacuum would still continue to be part of the Minkowski spacetime continuum of the observers, in particular with respect to simultaneity (e.g. of events happening at this place before or after your experiment). If your experiment is lasting one hour, during this hour the clocks of the observers will continue to run.

But in a space without mass particles there is no clock running. That implies that there is no proper time, no duration of anything inside.

Comment: You can have gravitational waves propagating at $c$ in a universe with no matter, and their behaviour is a function of time. So I disagree with your conclusion.

Comment: @John Rennie, you have to distinguish between spacetime and proper time: In your example the waves could be observed, clocks of observers are continuing to run in the relative spacetime of each observer. But the reciprocal Lorentz factor corresponding to the velocity c is 0, that means that there is no intrinsic proper time in the universe you are describing. Waves are a function of time, but they are not subject to any proper time.