# Can time exist without change?

Tags: time, vacuum

Time seems to be simply a measure of change, or rather how we perceive time is by observing the rate of change. If no change can be detected, no motion, no chemical change, no change of state, not even nuclear decay, does time itself even exist for that closed system?  Yes, an observer outside of that system could compare the system's change or lack thereof to something in the observer's world that is changing, such as a clock.

It is almost as if time does not exist until one can measure it.  This sounds similar to quantum mechanics theory regarding observation.   Is there a link?  I'm hoping there is an answer to my question that a non-physicist engineer could understand.

Comment: Time is that which the clocks show. The problem with our education system is that we don't teach what a clock mechanism is: it is a physical system with a local energy reservoir that releases this energy slowly and evenly towards infinity in form of radiation. Time doesn't exist because "we measure it". Time exists because there are physical mechanisms that release local energy towards infinity. Why is that possible? Because there is more "there" than there is "here", i.e. energy density is automatically being diluted in a three dimensional empty universe.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98917/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score -1):

Fundamentally, time is nothing but a concept that relates or compares at least two motions, for example, the moving hand of a clock is compared to earth's rotation. If nothing really changed (or moved) then you're right that concept of time indeed makes no sense.
However, in real life there's always something moving in this universe. According to relativity, light always travels at c relative to everything else. So, there's always something against which everything else can compare its motion, which is light. Hence, the concept of time is indispensable. Whether one measures it or not is irrelevant, because light is still travelling at c hence "time" would still "pass".

It's worth noting that light itself is a result of motion of charged particles. Charged particles interact with each other due to electromagnetic field. An accelerated charge creates "ripples" called light in this field which propagate at c, which can interact with another charged particle and cause this one to accelerate. This shows light acts as the fundamental "carrier" of causality. Event1 can't cause event2 before light reaches from former to the latter. This also establishes past-present-future relationship. Event1 must be further at past if it caused event2.

Since speed of light is source/observer independent, internal motions of an inertial frame would appear to run at different rates from other inertial frames, this is called time dilation. Time isn't a physical substance that expands/dilates, rather it's the motions that appear different (i.e clocks tick differently) depending on reference frames, giving rise to the concept of time dilation.

Comment: Thank you for that well-thought-out explanation.  I'm still trying to wrap my head around paragraph two.  I've never thought of light as a result of the motion of charged particles, per se.  But I should have, I guess because light is a Transverse wave.  Transverse waves, if I'm stating this correctly, are the motion of something perpendicular to the propagation of the wave

Comment: In the case of light that something that is moving transversely must be photons.  Correct?

Comment: I think I never fully understood intuitively how light is an electromagnetic wave.  That I think is because I've never intuitively understood how a photon can be since unlike an electron a photo has no mass.  How can any "particle" have no mass?  I don't dispute it, I just can't wrap my head around it, so far.